# Solution for "Failed to create query for method" findOne

Tags: spring-data-jpa

So, I was getting this exception when starting up my app that uses spring-data-jpa 2.0.3

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to create query for method public abstract package.Entity package.repositories.EntityRepository.findOne(java.lang.Integer)! No property findOne found for type Entity!
```

So, the issue was that my EntityRepository extends CrudRepository.  CrudRepository already provides the findOne() method.  A previous developer had duplicated the method in our EntityRepository interface.  By removing the duplicate method, everything worked.

I also had to remove the findAll() : List methods. In this case, it wasn't a straight removal, because the CrudRepository returns Iterable instead.  Still an easy fix.

Comment: Can you put the method signatures in EntityRepository

Comment: If you have a solution to your question, please post it as an answer instead of editing it into your question.

Comment: I didn't edit it, (except to put a code box around the exception).   So is your issue is that I should've split this into two parts?