# [Solution]:UnsatisfiedDependencyException in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

**GuestRepository.java**

```
public interface GuestRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<Guest,Integer> 
{
        Guest findOne(int id);
}
```

**ReservationService.java**

```
import java.util.*;

@Service
public class ReservationService {

    private RoomRepository roomRepository;
    private GuestRepository guestRepository;
    private ReservationRepository reservationRepository;

    @Autowired
    public ReservationService(RoomRepository roomRepository, GuestRepository guestRepository, ReservationRepository reservationRepository) {
        this.roomRepository = roomRepository;
        this.guestRepository = guestRepository;
        this.reservationRepository = reservationRepository;
    }

    public List<RoomReservation> getRoomReservationForDate(Date date){
        Iterable<Rooms> rooms=this.roomRepository.findAll();
        Map<Integer,RoomReservation> roomReservationMap=new HashMap<>();
        rooms.forEach(room->{
            RoomReservation roomReservation=new RoomReservation();
            roomReservation.setRoomId(room.getId());
            roomReservation.setFirstName(room.getName());
            roomReservation.setRoomNumber(room.getNumber());
            roomReservationMap.put(room.getId(),roomReservation);
        });

        Iterable<Reservation> reservations=this.reservationRepository.findByDate(new java.sql.Date(date.getTime()));
        if(reservations==null){
            reservations.forEach(reservation -> {
                Guest guest=this.guestRepository.findOne(reservation.getGuestId());
                if(guest==null){
                    RoomReservation roomReservation=roomReservationMap.get(reservation.getReservationId());
                    roomReservation.setDate(date);
                    roomReservation.setFirstName(guest.getFirstName());
                    roomReservation.setLastName(guest.getLastName());
                    roomReservation.setGuestId(guest.getGuest_id());
                }
            });
        }
        List<RoomReservation> roomReservations=new ArrayList<>();
        for (Integer roomId:roomReservationMap.keySet()){
            roomReservations.add(roomReservationMap.get(roomId));
        }
        return roomReservations;


    }

}
```

**ReservationApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class ReservationsApplication {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    ApplicationContext applicationContext=SpringApplication.run(ReservationsApplication.class, args);
    String[] beanNames=applicationContext.getBeanDefinitionNames();
    Arrays.sort(beanNames);
    for (String name:beanNames) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}
}
```

**Error**:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'reservationService'  defined in file
>   [/Users/ashlin/Downloads/reservations/target/classes/com/ashlinkarkada/reservations/business/service/ReservationService.class]:
>   Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor parameter 1;
>   nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'guestRepository': Invocation of init method
>   failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed
>   to create query for method public abstract
>   com.ashlinkarkada.reservations.data.entities.Guest
>   com.ashlinkarkada.reservations.data.repository.GuestRepository.findOne(int)!
>   No property findOne found for type Guest!

**Solution:**

```
public interface GuestRepository extends JpaRepository<Guest,Integer> {
@Override
Guest getOne(Integer integer);
}
```

Comment: This question https://stackoverflow.com/q/48547261/2553194 maybe useful. It includes the answer in the description of the problem.

Comment: Thanks. Since the method findOne is already taken , I had to override the "getOne()" method from the JpaRepository interface.